# How to map array inside message in Logstash HTTP Output

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file, logstash-jdbc, update-by-query

I am using Logstash to update by query existing Elasticsearch documents with an additional field that contains aggregate values extracted from Potgresql table.
I use elastichsearch output to load one index using document_id and http output to update another index that have different document_id but receving errors:

[2023-02-08T17:58:12,086][ERROR][logstash.outputs.http    ][main][b64f19821b11ee0df1bd165920785876cd6c5fab079e27d39bb7ee19a3d642a4] [HTTP Output Failure] Encountered non-2xx HTTP code 400 {:response_code=>400, :url=>"http://localhost:9200/medico/_update_by_query", :event=>#LogStash::Event:0x19a14c08}

This is my pipeline configuration:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        # Postgres jdbc connection string to our database, mydb
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://handel:5432/mydb"
        statement_filepath => "D:\ProgrammiUnsupported\logstash-7.15.2\config\nota_sede.sql"
    }
}

filter {
    aggregate {
        task_id => "%{idCso}"
        code => "
            map['idCso'] = event.get('idCso')
            map['noteSede'] ||= []
            map['noteSede'] << {
                'id' => event.get('idNota'),
                'tipo' => event.get('tipoNota'),
                'descrizione' => event.get('descrizione'),
                'data' => event.get('data'),
                'dataInizio' => event.get('dataInizio'),
                'dataFine' => event.get('dataFine')
            }
            event.cancel()"
        push_previous_map_as_event => true
        timeout => 60
        timeout_tags => ['_aggregatetimeout']       
    }
   }
}

output {

    stdout { codec => rubydebug { metadata => true } }

#       this works
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "https://localhost:9200"
        document_id => "STRUTTURA_%{idCso}" 
        index => "struttura"
        action => "update"
        user => "user"
        password => "password"
        ssl => true
        cacert => "/usr/share/logstash/config/ca.crt"   
    }
    
    http {
        url => "http://localhost:9200/medico/_update_by_query"
        user => "elastic"
        password => "changeme"
        http_method => "post"
        format => "message"
        content_type => "application/json"
        message => '{
                        "query":{
                            "term":{
                                "idCso":"%{idCso}"
                            }
                        },
                        "script":{
                            "source":"ctx._source.noteSede=params.noteSede",
                            "lang":"painless",
                            "params":{
                                "noteSede":"%{noteSede}"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }'
    }
}
```

The stdout output show me the sended docs to output like this:

```
{
     "query" => {
        "term" => {
            "idCso" => "859119"
        }
    },
    "script" => {
        "source" => "ctx._source.noteSede=params.noteSede",
        "lang" => "painless",
        "params" => {
            "noteSede" => "{dataFine=null, dataInizio=2020-02-13, descrizione=?, tipo=DB, id=6390644, data=2020-02-13 12:26:58.409},{dataFine=null, dataInizio=2020-02-13, descrizione=?, tipo=DE, id=6390645, data=2020-02-13 12:26:58.41}"
        }
        }
    }
}
```

How could I set noteSede array field into message to _update_by_query ?

Comment: What happens if you try to run the same update by query from Kibana Dev Tools? What response do you get? Can you find any error logs in the ES server logs?

Comment: Hi @Val, from Postman the following command works.
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "idCso":22868
        }
    },
    "script" : {
        "source" : "ctx._source.noteSede=params.noteSede",
        "lang" : "painless",
        "params": {
            "noteSede" : [
                {"dataInizio":"2020-02-13", "descrizione":"?", "tipo":"DB", "id":6390644, "data":"2020-02-13 12:26:58.409"},
                {"dataInizio":"2020-02-13", "descrizione":"?", "tipo":"DE", "id":6390645, "data":"2020-02-13 12:26:58.41"}
            ]
        }
    }
}

Comment: I think the problems stems from the fact that you're stringifying `noteSede`(i.e. `"noteSede": "%{noteSede}"`), whereas when you execute via Postman, you're not (i.e. `"noteSede" : [ {"d`)

Comment: @Val I added timeout_code => "event.set('noteSede', event.get('noteSede').to_json)" but
still getting this error from Logstash:
[2023-02-09T13:47:02,441][ERROR][logstash.outputs.http    ][main][432ed526006441ae331331c675bb9d8c124a6fd12ca1f2b274888cebc7ef5233] [HTTP Output Failure] Encountered non-2xx HTTP code 406 {:response_code=>406, :url=>"http://localhost:9200/struttura/_update_by_query", :event=>#<LogStash::Event:0x69078692>}
No error founded into Elastic server.

Comment: Have you tried removing the double quotes ?  `"noteSede":"%{noteSede}"` => `"noteSede":%{noteSede}`

Comment: Yes, get same error. I tried also with static code "noteSede":"xxx" and it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you run this so we get some [debug logging](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-http/blob/main/lib/logstash/outputs/http.rb#L278-L284) in Logstash: `curl -XPUT 'localhost:9600/_node/logging?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{ "logger.logstash.outputs.http" : "DEBUG"}'`

Comment: Debug log add these additional info at beginning:
[2023-02-10T09:33:37,545][DEBUG][logstash.outputs.http    ] config LogStash::Outputs::Http/@message = "{\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"query\":{\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\"term\":{\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\"idCso\":\"%{idCso}\"\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t\t\t},\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"script\":{\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\"source\":\"ctx._source.noteSede = params.noteSede\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\"lang\":\"painless\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\"params\":{\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\"noteSede\":\"xxx\"\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t\t}"

Comment: It would be nice if you could share the full log (e.g. via [gist](https://gist.github.com/))

Comment: Hi, I share configurations and log on this [link](https://gist.github.com/Carlitoz72/3323cbfd3a666d45f20112798f841f5a)

Comment: Thanks, but can you add the DEBUG logs to that gist?

Comment: Sorry, I update the log configuation with debug [link](https://gist.github.com/Carlitoz72/3323cbfd3a666d45f20112798f841f5a)

Comment: It doesn't contain the DEBUG messages from `logstash.outputs.http` like you had in your comment above. You need to re-rerun the curl above everytime you restart Lostash

Comment: @Val Cannot appy debug logging with curl because logstash crush as soon as it's started.

Answer (score 0):

I found the trick using ruby code for setting params array end set the format of http output to json. Possibile code optimization but it works!

```
ruby {
    code => '
        temp = event.get("noteSede")
        note = {"noteSede" => temp}
        event.set("script", "params" => note)
    '
}
mutate {
    add_field => {
        "[script][lang]" => "painless"
        "[query][term][idSede]" => '%{idSede}'
        "[script][source]" => "ctx._source.noteSede = params.noteSede"
    }
    remove_field => ["tags", "idSede", "noteSede", "@version", "@timestamp"]            
}
```

Bye